# org.apache.spark.SparkException: job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to solve the below problem statement using spark-shell in cloudera VM but getting error. Tried to follow few suggestions raised in other tickets on this site but not following. As I am new to this big data world so any help will be appreciated.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: **Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "patientID" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)**
```

**Problem Statement:**

You have been given below patient data in csv format,

```
patientID,name,dateOfBirth,lastVisitDate
1001,Ah Teck,1991-12-31,2012-01-20
1002,Kumar,2011-10-29,2012-09-20
1003,Ali,2011-01-30,2012-10-21
```

Accomplish following activities.

1 . Find all the patients whose lastVisitDate between current time and '2012-09-15'

Error message with scala code written in Spark-shell

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/avro/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.12.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
17/11/06 20:15:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Spark context available as sc (master = local[*], app id = local-1510028148251).
17/11/06 20:15:53 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@3de10177

scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

scala> val patients = sc.textFile("sparksql3/patients.csv")
patients: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = sparksql3/patients.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:35

scala> patients.first()
res0: String = 1001,Ah Teck,1999-12-31,2012-01-20

scala> case class Patient(patientId:Integer,name:String,dateOfBirth:String,lastVisitDate:String)
defined class Patient

scala> val patRDD = patients.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>Patient(p(0).toInt,p(1),p(2),p(3)))
patRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Patient] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:39

scala> patRDD.count()
17/11/06 20:27:01 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "patientID"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line35.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at $line35.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1635)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/11/06 20:27:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "patientID"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line35.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at $line35.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1635)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/11/06 20:27:02 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "patientID"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1635)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1445)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1627)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1616)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1862)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1959)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:65)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:67)
    at <init>(<console>:69)
    at .<init>(<console>:73)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "patientID"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1635)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1888)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading .csv file along with the header. Before creating the RDD you have to remove the header.

```
val patients = sc.textFile("sparksql3/patients.csv")
val header = patients.first()
val new_record = patients.filter(row => row!= header)
case class Patient(patientId:Integer,name:String,dateOfBirth:String,lastVisitDate:String)
val patRDD = new_record.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>Patient(p(0).toInt,p(1),p(2),p(3)))
patRDD.count() // 3
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I think the problem is bigger than that. I have tried your steps but didn't work. Though i have tried earlier both with header and without header but that time it didn't work as well.